# Dovecot duplicate usernames

Tags: authentication, dovecot

This is, perhaps, a strange thing to want to do, but I have reasons.

My dovecot auth is provided by data retrieved from SQL, so far normal. My passwords are in the appropriate format of `{scheme}data`, so that's fine.
The problem starts when I have two users with the same username.  When I do that I get this error:

```
auth-worker(32489): Error: sql(__variables__): Password query returned multiple matches
```

Well fudge.  Any thoughts on how I can get around that?

1. I considered using the %w variable to filter the sql results, but since the passwords might be in different schemes I can't do a straight test.
2. I considered using the %w variable and a stored procedure to find the right result, but then I'd have to do all the hashing in sql and that's a bad time.
3. I can make multiple different logins share the same maildir to get the retrieval part to behave the same, but creating more usernames is what I don't want to do.

The reasons I mentioned?  I have two use cases:

1. Email logins modelled to look more like API keys.  Create a username but have a separate password for each client connecting to it, if one gets compromised you can revoke it without having to change all the logins.
2. Different non-plaintext auth mechanisms have different intermediate products.  Instead of storing the plain text you can store the intermediates.  For the sake of example, you could store a value for the CRAM-MD5, SHA256 and OTP schemes.

Any clean way to make this work?

Comment: Ever considered using Dovecot's sharing features instead of abusing the defined authentication scheme?

Comment: @JensErat While I appreciate thought, it's not very constructive.  I'm aware of those features and can't see how they solve the stated requirement of not creating extra usernames.  Have I missed a detail when reading those docs?

Comment: @Kaithar Did you ever manage to solve your problem? I'm facing exactly the same...

Comment: @TylerDurden I pretty much abandoned the approach in favour of aliasing the usernames, such that alice+phone@example.com and alice+desktop@example.com are resolved to the same mailbox and everything.